# Retrieve data from NSArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

i am very new to this. I have stored all the `NSDictionary` into `NSArray` now i want to retrieve the data. I have no clue how to do that. Please help me on this. I want to get the both key and data and based on that want to show the data in `UITableView`. I have every thing only retrieving part is pending.

Below is my `NSArray` :

```
 {
    Code = MCP3441G;
    "Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Round Body MH";
    "Needle Dimension" = "31 MM";
    "No. of foils per box" = 12;
    "Per box maximum retail price" = 7440;
    "Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 5474;
    Size = "2/0";
    "Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL monofilament 70 CM Violet";
    nid = 86;
},
    {
    Code = NW1641;
    "Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Round Body";
    "Needle Dimension" = "30 MM";
    "No. of foils per box" = 12;
    "Per box maximum retail price" = 4800;
    "Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 3510;
    Size = "2/0 Only";
    "Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 CM";
    nid = 86;
},
    {
    Code = NW1642;
    "Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Round Body";
    "Needle Dimension" = "30 MM";
    "No. of foils per box" = 12;
    "Per box maximum retail price" = 4800;
    "Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 3510;
    Size = "1/0";
    "Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 CM";
    nid = 86;
},
    {
    Code = NW1648;
    "Needle Description" = "3/8 Circle Round Body";
    "Needle Dimension" = "16 MM";
    "No. of foils per box" = 12;
    "Per box maximum retail price" = 3600;
    "Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 2687;
    Size = "4/0";
    "Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 cm";
    nid = 86;
},
    {
    Code = NW1663;
    "Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Oval Round Body J.B";
    "Needle Dimension" = "22 MM";
    "No. of foils per box" = 12;
    "Per box maximum retail price" = 5280;
    "Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 3870;
    Size = "3/0";
    "Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 CM";
    nid = 86;
},
    {
    Code = NW1664;
    "Needle Description" = "1/2 Circle Oval Round Body J.B";
    "Needle Dimension" = "26 MM";
    "No. of foils per box" = 12;
    "Per box maximum retail price" = 5880;
    "Per box price to retailers & hospitals" = 4347;
    Size = "3/0";
    "Suture type and length" = "MONOCRYL Undyed Monofilament 70 CM";
    nid = 86;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of accessing the data.  First, I recommend you look at the documentation for both NSArray (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) and NSDictionary (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/)

To access a certain element of the NSArray, you can do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*) myArray[0]; //gets the first item of the array.
```

Once you have the dictionary, there are many possible ways of accessing the keys and data.  If you have the key and you want a specific value, you could do something like this:

```
NSString *desc = dict[@"Needle Description"]; //gets the value for the key Needle Description
```

(Note the above uses a shorthand -- you could also do the more verbose `[dict objectForKey:@"Needle Description"]`)

You can also get arrays of all of the keys (for listing in a table, as you described in your question), but doing something like:

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
```

Then, you could loop through those keys, and poll for the values item by item.

Again, check the documentation for even more ways of getting the info out.